# transformar arquivos em pdf com o pdfjs

Tags: angular, pdf, html2pdf-js

Tenho um componente para fazer o envio de arquivos ao back end, porem preciso que esses arquivos sejam transformados em pdf. Pensando nisso, estou utilizando o PDFJs, passando o elemento output para ele, porem notei que não está funcionando.

segue meu cod

```
testePdf(file) {
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let content = this.upload.nativeElement;
    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 190,
    });
    doc.save('test.pdf');
  }
```

ele está retornando vazio, onde estou errando?

estou utilizando o dashboard do uppy para upload

Answer (score 0):

Talvez possa ajudar com alguma idéia. Tive um problema parecido utilizando o jsPDF, parece que os métodos de html estão depreciados (tanto o [`addHTML`](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML) quanto o `fromHTML`), a saída que encontrei foi a seguinte:

instalar [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) e o resultado do canvas, jogar como imagem para o PDF:

```
generatePdf(element: HTMLElement, filename: string): Promise<void> {
  const options = {
    background: 'white',
    imageTimeout: 1000,
    useCORS: true,
    scale: 1.5
  };

  html2canvas(element, options).then((canvas) => {
    const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/PNG");
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

    // Add image Canvas to PDF
    const bufferX = 5;
    const bufferY = 5;
    const imgProps = (<any>doc).getImageProperties(img);
    const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 2 * bufferX;
    const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
    doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, undefined, 'FAST');

    return doc;
  }).then((doc) => {
    return doc.save(filename);
  });
}
```

Comment: pensei nisso, mas o usuario poderar subir até um arquivo xlr, to preocupada por não sei se atende